# How to subtract multiple subpaths from a shape easily in Illustrator or Sketch?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, workflow, pathfinder, sketch-app

I am using Sketch (app) that has Boolean drawing operations (like subtract, union, intersect...) as in Illustrator.
In my file I have four ring shapes. They are not strokes but more like circles with holes in them. My goal is to subtract the black rings and the red shape so it produces a wifi symbol composed of 4 black vector shapes.

What are the fewest steps needed to extract the black shapes to produce the vector below?

The answer can apply to Illustrator or Sketch specifically.

[image: screenshot of project objects]
[image: my desired result]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Illustrator...

Select it all, `Pathfinder > Merge`, click the red, hit delete.

Or

Select it all, grab the **Shape Builder Tool**, Hold down the Option/Alt and click-drag starting below the rings, to the center ring covered by red.

Comment: This does the trick. I was trying to give Sketch a chance but it has no _merge_ function like in Illustrator from what i see. The other boolean functions produce nothing good.